# How to detect canny edge and integral projection on a real time webcam using c# aforge?

Tags: c#, real-time, webcam, projection, aforge

"I have been trying to detect canny edge on an image and it has been successful, but I don't know how to detect its edge if I want it real time, here is my code, it has no error but the canny window can't be processed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using KomCit;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Threading;

namespace canny_video
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevice;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalFrame;

        void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            CameraBox.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }

        private static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //timer1.Enabled = true;
            CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
            {
                listDevice.Items.Add(Device.Name);

            }
            listDevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
        }

        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[listDevice.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            FinalFrame.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
            FinalFrame.Start();
            //CannyBox.Image = (Bitmap)CameraBox.Image.Clone();    //capture image bitmap
            //Bitmap gambar = new Bitmap(CameraBox.Image);
            Bitmap gambar = new Bitmap(CameraBox.Image);
            Grayscale gray = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
            CannyEdgeDetector cany = new CannyEdgeDetector(0, 70);
            Bitmap hasil = cany.Apply(gray.Apply(gambar));
            // BlobsFiltering blob = new BlobsFiltering(0, 0, 20, 20);
            //Bitmap hasil = blob.Apply(gray.Apply(gambar));
            //CannyBox.Width = gambar.Width;
            //CannyBox.Height = gambar.Height;
            CannyBox.Image = hasil;
        }



        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalFrame.IsRunning == true)
            {
                FinalFrame.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"

My problem above is solved, thank you :)
but I have another problem on integral projection, I didn't know how to do it though.
please help, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- Your two private variables are very confusingly named. Your `CaptureDevice` is a collection of all the capture devices on the computer, while your `FinalFrame` is a capture device.
- You do not look for canny edges on the bitmap upon reception.
- The NewFrame event handler runs in the streaming thread, so you should use a `.BeginInvoke` in there to make it usable by the UI thread.

What you may do:

- Inside _NewFrame handler, use BeginInvoke to transfer the cloned image to a `ProcessCameraImage` method (that will hence run on the UI thread).
- Apply canny edge detection within this method.
- Then assign the result to your picture box.

Note: I don't know how CPU heavy canny edge detection is. If it's costly, doing it on the UI thread may block user interaction. In that case you could do it within the streaming thread and only transfer the processed image for display. But depending on the time it takes, this may force the camera to lower its framerate.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes it is delayed about 5 seconds to do the detection, could you tell me how to reduce its delay? its troubling me

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, it has been solved just now, I've modified it and it somehow solved

here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;       //Save P2
using System.IO;                    //Save P2

namespace AForgeCamera
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        Bitmap video;

        private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevice;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalFrame;
        int mode;



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      //Tombol Start
        {
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
            FinalFrame.Start();
        }
        void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            Bitmap video2 = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            if (mode==1)
            {
                Grayscale gray = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
                Bitmap video3 = gray.Apply(video2);
                CannyEdgeDetector canny = new CannyEdgeDetector(0, 70);
                canny.ApplyInPlace(video3);
                pictureBox2.Image = video3;
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = video;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalFrame.IsRunning == true)
            {
                FinalFrame.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void btnTrackingObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mode = 1;
        }


    }
}
```

but now I am working on the next problem, I try to detect the location of the object using integral projection, is it possible to use aforge to do it?